# How does Dojo/jQuery Mobile/etc fit into mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, web

What's the intent behind a framework like [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) in the context of developing a cross-platform app?

I want to rapidly prototype a mobile app GUI that includes a schedule/calendar. In this case, would I use Dojo instead of just PhoneGap because I would want to also have a web browser based app that goes alone with my mobile app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile JavaScript frameworks like those provided by Dojo or jQuery theoretically allow you to
write mobile browser independent client side code for web based applications.  In other words, you as the developer do not need to be concerned with writing specific code for each mobile browser.

Answer (score 2):

Dojo (or other JS mobile toolkit) and PhoneGap are generally complimentary.  PhoneGap is for access to native device services which aren't yet reflected to the browser, like camera or telco access.  Dojo and the other toolkits generally let you create mobile-style UIs (may also run on Desktop browser, but would look like a phone) and handle things like touch and scroll gestures.  And, as Peter says, cross-browser issues are also handled for you.